# Label before Get Post Meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using `get_post_meta` string to display a number ( `qty_order` ) value on the front-end.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'qty_order', true); ?>
```

All works great and it returns my Qty Order number, but I need to show a label "Quantity Order" together with the number.

How can I add the label in front of the string to display with the value?

Comment: an HTML label?... or you just want to place a string of text before it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below :

```
<?php
$qtOrder =  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'qty_order', true);
if(!empty($qtOrder)) {
  echo "Quantity Order ".$qtOrder;
}
?>
```

Comment: That works, many thanks, the only problem is that if the `qty_order`field is not set, the label displays anyway.

Is there a way to fix this to only display the label if the filed value is set?

Answer (score 2):

You can add your label like this:

```
Quantity Order: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'qty_order', true); ?>
```

Or if you want to add an HTML label:

```
<label>Quantity Order</label><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'qty_order', true); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You use default woocommerce lable with custom class like this:

```
<label for="qty_order" class="custom_label">Quantity Order :</lable>
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'qty_order', true); ?>
```